# Optimized way for multiple conditions on pandas dataframe columns value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am applying multiple filters on a dataframe at the same time.

```
data_df[(data_df['1']!=0) & (data_df['2']==0) & (data_df['3']==0) & (data_df['4']==0) & (data_df['5']==0)]
```

I needed to know is there any optimized way to do this? As I want to compare one column's value as !=0 and others value as =0 multiple times and columns could be more than 5. So, all operations will be:

```
data_df[(data_df['1']==0) & (data_df['2']!=0) & (data_df['3']==0) & (data_df['4']==0) & (data_df['5']==0)]
data_df[(data_df['1']==0) & (data_df['2']==0) & (data_df['3']!=0) & (data_df['4']==0) & (data_df['5']==0)]
data_df[(data_df['1']==0) & (data_df['2']==0) & (data_df['3']==0) & (data_df['4']!=0) & (data_df['5']==0)]
data_df[(data_df['1']==0) & (data_df['2']==0) & (data_df['3']==0) & (data_df['4']==0) & (data_df['5']!=0)]
```

Looking for a short and optimized method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the below statements:

> Looking for a short and optimized method

and

> I want to compare one column's value as !=0 and others value as =0

You can use [`df.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and [`df.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`df.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) on `axis=1` to drop the column `1`:

```
data_df[data_df[1].ne(0) & data_df.drop(1,axis=1).eq(0).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: I cannot change answer, because was deleted ;)

Comment: @jezrael no problem, thanks a lot for editing. i didnt have the laptop for a while to test :)

Comment: @HammadHassan it is advisable to create a sample dataframe and expected output  in the question according to the conditions, this way the question will be clearer and the future readres can also derive value out of this question :)

Answer (score 2):

One idea is compare by numpy array filled by `1` and `0` and test if all values matching by [`numpy.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
#test list - all 0, first 1
L = [1,0,0,0,0]

df = data_df[np.all(data_df == np.array(L), axis=1)]
```

Or use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by one row `DataFrame`:

```
df = data_df.merge(pd.DataFrame([L], columns=data_df.columns))
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
data_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(100, 5)), columns=list('12345'))
#print (data_df)

df = data_df[np.all(data_df == np.array(L), axis=1)]
print (df)
    1  2  3  4  5
2   1  0  0  0  0
13  1  0  0  0  0
44  1  0  0  0  0
58  1  0  0  0  0
70  1  0  0  0  0
89  1  0  0  0  0
```

Or:

```
L = [1,0,0,0,0]
df = data_df.merge(pd.DataFrame([L], columns=data_df.columns))
print (df)
   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  0  0
3  1  0  0  0  0
4  1  0  0  0  0
5  1  0  0  0  0
```

Solution with `merge` should be used with helper `DataFrame` with all combinations:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=data_df.columns, columns=data_df.columns)
np.fill_diagonal(df1.to_numpy(), 1)
print (df1)
   1  2  3  4  5
1  1  0  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  1  0  0
4  0  0  0  1  0
5  0  0  0  0  1

df = data_df.merge(df1.loc[['1']])
print (df)
   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  0  0
3  1  0  0  0  0
4  1  0  0  0  0
5  1  0  0  0  0

df = data_df.merge(df1.loc[['2']])
print (df)
   1  2  3  4  5
0  0  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

We can first calculate the dataframe, such that for the given columns we only calculate once if the value is equal to zero or not.

```
df_bool = df[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']] == 0
```

Next we can use this as a mask:

```
df[~df_bool[1] & df[[2, 3, 4, 5]].all(axis=1)]
```